# Is scaling of feature values in LibSVM necessary?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, svm, libsvm

If I have 200 features, and if each feature can have a value ranging from 0 to infinity, should I scale the feature values to be in the range [0-1] before I go ahead and train a LibSVM  on top of it?

Now, suppose I did scale the values, and after training the model if I get one vector with its values or the features as input, how do I scale these values of the input test vector before classifying it?

Thanks
Abhishek S

Comment: Did you **try** using unscaled data? Does it give other results than scaled data?

Comment: Yes, I just ran an experiment with and without scaling. I saw that the performance improved with scaling. Thanks for pointing it out. It was useful! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got infinite feature values, you're not going to be able to use LIBSVM anyway.

More practically, scaling is generally useful so the kernel doesn't have to deal with large numbers, so I would say go for it and scale. It's not a requirement, though.

And as Anony-Mousse implied in the comments, *please* try running experiments with and without scaling so *you* can see the difference.

> Now, suppose I did scale the values, and after training the model if I get one vector with its values or the features as input, how do I scale these values of the input test vector before classifying it?

You don't need to scale again. You already did that in the pre-training step (i.e. data processing).

Comment: If you downvote, please explain why so we can learn from the reason.

Comment: -1: Answering without understanding the question: 1) "You don't need to scale again..." - you should scale the extracted value from unknown instance - not rescaling training data of cause. 2) " so the kernel doesn't have to deal with large numbers" ??? For a computer it doesn't matter, if a real number is large or small. Scaling is required not to make values smaller but for unifying the ranges, when the value ranges between features vary considerably - e.g F1 [0.0001-0.001] and F2[100000-2000000000]

Answer (score 3):

You should store the ranges of you feature-values used for training. Then when you extract a feature-value from an unknown instance, use the particular range for scaling.

Use the formula (here for the range [-1.0 , 1.0]):

```
double scaled_val = -1.0 + (1.0 - -1.0) * (extracted_val - vmin)/(vmax-vmin);
```

The [Guide](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf) provided at libsvm website explains the scaling well:

*"2.2 Scaling
Scaling before applying SVM is very important. Part 2 of Sarle's Neural Networks
FAQ Sarle (1997) explains the importance of this and most of considerations also apply
to SVM. The main advantage of scaling is to avoid attributes in greater numeric
ranges dominating those in smaller numeric ranges. Another advantage is to avoid
numerical diculties during the calculation. Because kernel values usually depend on
the inner products of feature vectors, e.g. the linear kernel and the polynomial kernel,
large attribute values might cause numerical problems. We recommend linearly
scaling each attribute to the range [-1; +1] or [0; 1].
Of course we have to use the same method to scale both training and testing
data."*